Different XVA Frameworks
I was wondering about the different possibilities about implement an XVA framework within a firm to calculate the different components.
As far as I understand one of the main methodologies is the one employed by Burgard and Kjaer. Apparently, Piterbarg also has a model for the counterparty credit risk adjustments which is better suited for the Greeks calculations.
Would you know what are the main differences between both and which one would be more appropriate to use? Is there any additional framework widely used in the industry?
Thanks!
